# show that $P: \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{ R}$ is not surjective

Tags: polynomials

I have a problem where I have to prove that if {P} is a polynomial of even (positive) degree, then $P: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is not surjective.

I have proven that a polynomial of odd degree is surjective but i have no idea how to deal with this one. Any idea?

Thank you

Comment: @skyking Yes, I know that the limit is plus infinit when x goes to -/+ infinit for $a_{2n}>0$

Comment: You should probably tell what you have tried in the question and where you've got stuck.

Comment: @skyking I think I have made my self clear in the question where I am stuck. I have proven that a polynomial of odd degree is surjective but I don't know how to prove that if {P} is a polynomial of even (positive) degree, then $P: \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{ R}$ is not surjective

Comment: Noting that $P$ is continuous, on any interval $[a,b]$ ($a,b\in\mathbb{R}$), can $P$ have a maximum or minimum that is not finite?

Comment: @ben If the limit is $+\infty$ that would mean that there is an $\omega$ such that $P(x)>0$ for all $|x|>\omega$. What can you say about the values of $P(x)$ for $|x|\le\omega$? Is it bounded?

Comment: @skyking I got it now. Thanks. Solved.

Answer (score 1):

Hint : Try to show that (Assuming that the leading coefficient of $P$ is positive)

$$\lim_{x\to + \infty} P(x) = \lim_{x \to -\infty} P(x) = + \infty.$$

Then there is $M>0$ so that $P(x)>1$ for all $|x|>M$.

Comment: 1. This is not true (the limits could both be $-\infty$). 2. It doesn't answer the question: Knowing that $P(x)>1$ for all $|x|>M$ is not sufficient to conclude that $P$ is not surjective.

Comment: @AlexKruckman : Thanks for pointing that out. (And normally I would not give complete answer to question that haven't shown any work. And the OP is asking for ideas)